# Mantener un formulario abierto con un select

Tags: php, html5

En mi código cumple la funcion de que dependiendo que seleccione en select me muestre un formulario, ahora al calcular con los datos llenados al formulario me toca volver a seleccionar para que me muestre la respuesta y se borran los datos llenos en los input, hay alguna manera de que al recargar la pagina para el calculo ya este mostrado el formulario.
cualquier recomendación para mejorar el código o tenerlo ordenado sera bienvenido.
**Código**

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Ejercisio de ley de Boyle</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="#" method="post">
    Estado actual: 
    <select id="status" name="status" onChange="mostrar(this.value);">
        <option>Escoja una opcion</option>
        <option value="v1">Volumen1</option>
        <option value="v2">Volumen2</option>
        <option value="p1">Presion1</option>
        <option value="p2">Presion2</option>
     </select>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function mostrar(id) {
    if (id == "v1") {
        $("#v1").show();
        $("#v2").hide();
        $("#p1").hide();
        $("#p2").hide();
    }

    if (id == "v2") {
        $("#v1").hide();
        $("#v2").show();
        $("#p1").hide();
        $("#p2").hide();
    }

    if (id == "p1") {
        $("#v1").hide();
        $("#v2").hide();
        $("#p1").show();
        $("#p2").hide();
    }

    if (id == "p2") {
        $("#v1").hide();
        $("#v2").hide();
        $("#p1").hide();
        $("#p2").show();
    }
}
</script>
<div id="v1" style="display: none;">
    <h2>Si falta Volumen 1</h2>
    
        <form action="#" method="post">
        <p>volumen#2:<br/>
        <input type="number" name="Vol2"  /> Litros</p>
        <p>Presion#1:<br/>
        <input type="number" name="Pre1"  /> Atm</p>
        <p>Presion#2:<br/>
        <input type="number" name="Pre2"  /> Atm</p>
        <input type="submit" value="Enviar" name="send1">
        </form>
        <form action="Ejercisiophp.php">
        <input type="submit" value="Resetear" />
    </form>
        <?php
            $vol2="";
            $pre1="";
            $pre2="";

            if($_POST)
            {
                error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);
                $vol2 =$_POST["Vol2"];
                $pre1 =$_POST["Pre1"];
                $pre2 =$_POST["Pre2"];
            }
            ?>
            <?php
           if (isset($_POST["send1"])) {
            $vol=($vol2*$pre2)/$pre1; 
            echo "El volumen uno es:". $vol;       
            }
         ?>
            
</div>

<div id="v2" style="display: none;">
    <h2>Si falta Volumen2.</h2>
    <form action="#" method="post">
        <p>volumen#1<br/>
        <input type="text" name="Vol12" /></p>
        <p>Presion#1:<br/>
        <input type="text" name="Pre12" /></p>
        <p>Presion#2:<br/>
        <input type="text" name="Pre22" /></p>
        <input type="submit" name="send2" value="Enviar" />
    </form>
    <form action="Ejercisiophp.php">
        <input type="submit" value="Resetear" />
    </form>
    <?php
    
            $vol12="";
            $pre12="";
            $pre22="";

            if($_POST)
            {
                $vol12 =$_POST["Vol12"];
                $pre12 =$_POST["Pre12"];
                $pre22 =$_POST["Pre22"];
            }
            ?>
            <?php
           if (isset($_POST["send2"])) {
            error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);
            $vo=($vol12*$pre22)/$pre12; 
            echo "El volumen dos es:". $vo;       
            }
         ?>
</div>

<div id="p1" style="display: none;">
    <h2>Si falta Presion1</h2>
    <form action="#" method="post">
        <p>Volumen#1<br/>
        <input type="text" name="Vol13" /></p>
        <p>Volumen#2:<br/>
        <input type="text" name="Vol23" /></p>
        <p>Presion#2:<br/>
        <input type="text" name="Pre23" /></p>
        <input type="submit" name="send3" value="Enviar" />
    </form>
    <form action="Ejercisiophp.php">
        <input type="submit" value="Resetear" />
    </form>
    <?php
            $vol13="";
            $vol23="";
            $pre23="";

            if($_POST)
            {
               $vol13 =$_POST["Vol13"];
               $vol23 =$_POST["Vol23"];
               $pre23 =$_POST["Pre23"];
            }
            ?>
            <?php
           if (isset($_POST["send3"])) {
            error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);
            $pe=($vol23*$pre23)/$vol13; 
            echo "La presion uno es:". $pe;       
            }
         ?>
</div>
<div id="p2" style="display: none;">
    <h2>Si falta la Presion2 </h2>
    <form action="#" method="post">
        <p>Volumen#1<br/>
        <input type="text" name="Vol14" /></p>
        <p>Volumen#2:<br/>
        <input type="text" name="Vol24" /></p>
        <p>Presion#1:<br/>
        <input type="text" name="Pre14" /></p>
        <input type="submit" name="send4" value="Enviar" />
    </form>
    <form action="Ejercisiophp.php">
        <input type="submit" value="Resetear" />
    </form>
    <?php
            $vol14="";
            $vol24="";
            $pre14="";

            if($_POST)
            {
               $vol14 =$_POST["Vol14"];
               $vol24 =$_POST["Vol24"];
               $pre14 =$_POST["Pre14"];
            }
            ?>
            <?php
           if (isset($_POST["send4"])) {
            error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);
            $pre=($vol14*$pre14)/$vol24; 
            echo "La presion uno es:". $pre;       
            }
         ?>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Es un proyecto esta relacionado a la resolución de ejercicios con formula específicamente del área de química.

Comment: Si necesitas recargar **sólo** una parte de la página y conservar datos, te recomiendo que uses `Javascript` para realizar todo en del lado del cliente sin necesidad de realizar peticiones al servidor enviando y regresando datos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para esto, necesitas utilizar **AJAX**, Puedes leer [Qué es frontend y backend](https://descubrecomunicacion.com/que-es-backend-y-frontend/)

Para hacer eso corto, frontend es el lado del cliente (lo que se muestra en el navegador, HTML, CSS y JS) y backend es el lado del servidor (Con gran cantidad de lenguajes como PHP, Ruby, Perl, Python, Etc..) y AJAX es la forma de recibir y enviar datos al servidor.

NOTA: AJAX **NO** es un método para hacer cambios en tiempo real, para esto puedes usar **Web Sockets**

Explicado todo esto, tu pregunta tiene una solución muy sencilla

```javascript
$("#status").on("input", () => {
    $("#v1").hide();
    $("#v2").hide();
    $("#p1").hide();
    $("#p2").hide();
    $($("#status").val()).show();
});

$("#v1, #v2, #p1, #p2").on("submit", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST", // Método de envío
        data: {
            someinfo:true, // Información a enviar
        },
        url:"archivo", // Dónde se enviará la petición
        success: (msg) => {
            console.log(msg); // Mensaje del servidor
        },
        error: () => {
            console.log("Error en la petición");
        }
    });
});
```

Esto enviará una petición al servidor y no recargará la página, puedes ver el resultado de la petición en la consola, he tenido en cuenta que usas jQuery, si en un momento quieres reemplazar esto con JavaScript nativo, usa `fetch`

`fetch` es un método de JavaScript para hacer llamadas AJAX, puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera

```javascript
fetch("url", {
    method:"GET"
}).then(resp => resp.text()).then(resp => console.log(resp)).cath(err=>console.log(err));
```

`.then()` es el método para deducir si la petición fue exitosa y `.catch()` es el método para deducir si la petición tuvo algún error

Compatibilidad: `fetch()` es compatible con **TODOS** los navegadores

AJAX Antes de `EcmaScript 6`

Antes de `ES6`, se usaban las `XMLHttpRequest` (Siguen estando disponibles de uso, pero menos usadas) y tienen la siguiente forma

```javascript
let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "url"); // Método, URL
xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
        if (xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status <= 299) {
            console.log(xhr.responseText); // Petición exitosa
        } else {
            console.log("Error en la petición AJAX");
        }
    }
}
xhr.send("someInfo=abc&abc=bcd");
```

En `xhr.send()` enviamos la información de la petición al servidor, envía la información como parámetros de URL sin importar si utilizas POST.

Comment: muchas gracias, probare ahora